# Chromecast doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: chromecast

I tried to use chrome browser latest to cast tab or desktop. It used to work on my Ubuntu 20.04 on same laptop. is it a bug on 20.10?

Comment: What is the chrome version and did you check if there is a know issue with that version? Your title is misleading Chromecast is a piece of hardware.

Comment: The version which doesn't work is google-chrome-stable/stable,now 88.0.4324.182-1 amd64 [installed]

Comment: Here is the link to the know bugs in that version https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=chromium;dist=unstable

Answer (score 0):

The entire 88 version has chromecast integration broken. I downgraded it to the last 87 stable version which is working nicely. Try this:

```
wget "https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_87.0.4280.141-1_amd64.deb"
sudo dpkg -i "google-chrome-stable_87.0.4280.141-1_amd64.deb"
```